# A finite group $G$ and fixed $k\geq 1$ where for every $n\geq 1$, the $n$-direct product $G^n=G\times\dots\times G$ is $k$-generated?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, direct-product, combinatorial-group-theory

Does exist a finite group $G$ and fixed $k \geq 1$ such that the $n$-direct product $G^n = G \times \dots \times G$ is $k$-generated for every $n \geq 1$?

I suspect the answer is no. Does exist a simple proof of this fact (if true)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. For given $k$ and sufficiently large $n$, the projections of all $k$ putative generators would be equal on two different components,  and so they could not generate the full direct product.

To be more precise, if $h(k)$ is the number of surjective homomorphisms from the free group $F_k$ of rank $k$ to $G$ up to equivalence under automorphisms of $G$, then $G^{h(k)}$ is $k$-generated, but $G^{h(k)+1}$ is not. A well-known example (due I think to Philip Hall)  is $A_5^{19}$ is $2$-generated but $A_5^{20}$ is not.

Comment: If you (the OP, not Derek) are not familiar with free groups, $h(k)$ is the number of generating $k$-tuples in $G$, modulo the action of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$. Then proving Derek's assertion that $G^{h(k)+1}$ is not $k$-generated is an exercise.

Comment: Another exercise is to calculate or estimate the probability that two randomly chosen elements of $A_5^{19}$ generate it. I don't remember the answer, but it's very small!

Comment: If I'm correct there are 780 non-generating pairs (among 3600 pairs), so already the probability $(1-780/3600)^{19}\sim 0.0097$ that *each* of 19 pairs is generating, is quite small.

Comment: I make it $1320 = 60 + 15\times 36 + 20 \times 24 + 24 \times 10$ non-generating pairs $(g,h)$, with $60, 36, 24$, and $10$ possible $h$ when $g$ has order $1,2,3,5$ .That gives $.00017$ as the probability that a random pair projects onto each component. Of course the probability that they generate the direct product is less than that.

Comment: It seems I indeed missed many generating pairs (probably those generating copies of $A_4$). This makes $2280=120\times 19$ generating pairs. Assuming that the orbits under the automorphism group all have the same size, this makes, for $19$ random generating pairs, the probability $1/r$ to make a generating 19-tuple, where $r=2280^{19}/(120^{19}\times 19!)\sim 16263866$. And I guess that this value of $1/r$ is an upper bound in any case. And this is just among 19-tuples of generating pairs. Among all 19-tuples of pairs, one has to multiply by your $.00017$, which gives $\le 1/(95\times10^9)$.